# Extending the disk space of a server caused a major error on the disk

Tags: server, disk-management

I was extending my VPS disk space and during that process some error occurred and it changed everything. Now I'm not able to access anything.

Current disk status:

[image: Disk Status Right now]

There is very important data on the disk. I want to restore my system disks to the previous version.

Previous version of disk:

[image: Previous it does look like this]

I want this disk which is marked below.

[image: lsblk command status]

Comment: You took a backup of your important data before you started messing with disk partitions .. Right ?? 

Comment: No :( 
I didn't   took the backup

Comment: Sorry - I hope you do next time. Also, there isn't really any information here to go on. You should probably contact your VPS provider to see if they have an earlier snapshot or something.

Comment: is there anyway now to restore it?

Comment: The first thing I would do in your position is make an exact copy of that drive externally - *carefully* use dd to clone it to an external drive. Then ideally work on the clone, but at least you’ve copied it before you start. Your data may or may not be recoverable, but you can certainly make things worse with some attempts. Have a look on this site (and elsewhere) at the data recovery tools.